# How can we detect seasonality in a time series without looking at its plot?

Tags: time-series, seasonality

I am wondering if is there a way that we can mathematically or statistically identify seasonality in time series without the need to look at its plot?

Comment: What type of seasonality are you interested in detecting? See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/346497/time-series-seasonality-test for a nice breakdown of different types of seasonality.

Comment: See this post by Rob Hyndman for a possible answer to your question: https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/detecting-seasonality/.

Comment: Try searching unobserved components model/state space models, it has features to check/detect seasonalities