# SARIMA with a year to year dataset

Tags: time-series

I have a time series dataset that has yearly data points, and we can see that there is recurring pattern every few years

[image]

My question is : can I use SARIMA with this model, by changing my dataset as a time series dataset that has a frequency? as technically speaking there are no seasonality components, would that be frowned upon?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly you can do that, if you know the frequency of your seasonality. After all, there are annual time series that do exhibit cyclical behavior, e.g., sunspots have an 11-year cyclicality and could thus be modeled using SARIMA.

That said, I do not see a recurring pattern in your time series, other than "sometimes it's high, and then it usually comes down again, perhaps after a while, except when it doesn't, and then it goes up again, usually at least". May I suggest that you are at least open to the possibility that you are reading more into your data than is actually there? Unless there is some theory that underpins a five-year cycle (say), but not a seven-year one, I would be very careful indeed. (And note that humans are *very* good at *post hoc* explanations of stuff, even if those explanations do not help in predicting.)

Answer (score 0):

Building on Stephan's answer, if you do think there is a seasonal pattern in your data, I would certainly apply some tests for seasonality to your data instead of just eyeballing it. I think [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/346497/time-series-seasonality-test#:%7E:text=An%20other%20method%20to%20detect,the%20ACF%20(autocorrelation%20function).&text=And%20last%2C%20but%20not%20least,the%20Wilcoxon%20Signed%20Rank%20Test.) is a great place to start.