# Test for seasonality with LR-test?

Tags: regression, time-series, likelihood, seasonality, likelihood-ratio

I have an economic time series in monthly frequency. I want to test for seasonality using LR-Test. So the idea is to:

1. Regress the time series y on a model with a time trend and 12 seasonal dummy
2. Estimate a restricted form of this model by restricting all seasonal dummies = 0
3. Comparing the two models (restricted and unrestricted) with a Likelihood-Ratio Test (lrtest() in R)

Are there any objections doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time series seasonality test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/346497/time-series-seasonality-test)

Comment: Not 100%. I understand that the methods stated there are valid, but is my approach too?